# mount a folder in docker machine using docker for mac

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I'm trying to mount a folder (/Users/.../src) on mac inside a docker container :

```
docker run -v /Users/.../src:/sharedVolume/git_src_on_mac -v <DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME> /bin/bash
```

and it returns the following error:

```
Unable to find image '<DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME>:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: repository <DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME> not found: does not exist or no pull access.
```

I'm using docker for mac Version 1.13.1, and here is the output of `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                       NAMES
1ea17c622f80        <DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME>     "/test/myproject.sh"      About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:32783->5000/tcp   <DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME>
```

Does anyone know what is the issue?

Comment: What is the version for your docker machine image check `docker images -a` ?

Comment: `<DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME>         latest              1e2cebd5fa67        2 days ago          949 MB`

Answer (score 0):

(Got the idea from @FaigB comment): I should have used the name of the image (`docker image -a`) with `latest` tag

```
docker run -v /Users/.../src:/sharedVolume/git_src_on_mac -i -t <DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME>:latest /bin/bash
```